# How do you set binding of ComboBox ItemsSource in UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Here is the combobox in my UserControl:

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItemsProperty}" />
```

I have tried:

```
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
bind.Source = this;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("ComboItemsProperty");
this.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);
```

However, this doesn't work.  I think I am doing the bind.Source wrong, but I'm not sure what to set the Source to.  This code is inside my UserControl.xaml.cs.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the binding in both XAML and code behind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a binding to a Combox in a UserControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303937/how-can-i-set-a-binding-to-a-combox-in-a-usercontrol)

Comment: Make sure you don't change the value of ItemsSource locally, that would invalidate the binding. Other than that, your code seems fine. Look at the output window in VisualStudio, what is the binding error its giving you?

Comment: @B-Rad Did my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12321543/468718) helped you ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a lot of ways to do this, however, nothing seems to work.

I am instead going to serialize the binding when the .xaml file gets saved out.  This seems to be working perfectly.  Binding will no longer have to be set in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (Replace this)

```
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
bind.Source = yourCollectionSourceOrClass; //<--Replace with your collection
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("ComboItemsProperty");
this.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);
```

Comment: could you please answer my question on this link please? I have similar kind of unsolved problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609074/how-to-update-combobox-value-on-changing-selection-c-sharp-dynamically-using-bin

Answer (score 0):

You need to the set context of the instance containing your property **ComboItemsProperty**. So instead of 'this' u should set it to 'this.DataContext' or other class object instance containing the ItemSource property you have defined..

Try this,

```
Binding bind = new Binding();  
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;  
bind.Source = this.DataContext;  
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("ComboItemsProperty");  
this.SetBinding( ComboBox. ItemsSource Property, bind);
```

(posting frm mobile)

Comment: @MarkKall could you please answer my question on this link please? I have similar kind of unsolved problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609074/how-to-update-combobox-value-on-changing-selection-c-sharp-dynamically-using-bin