# How to update combobox value on changing selection c# dynamically using Binding() in c# (not xaml)

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I am c# silverlight5 beginner and i have a situation that i have to created a combo box dynamically using c# and kept items in it. But the problem now when i run it run properly showing  the last value by default but when i select the another value it don't update the that value in the text box near by because it is not working dynamically.

I guess i need to add some selection changed or some other event using c#. But i dont know how to do that. Please note that i have created this combo box using c# only.

**How to change the value in correspondng selection to the combobox value ?(just using c#)**

Comment: Please post some of your code so we can help you in where you are doing wrong or so..

Comment: @HarshBaid see below the solution. I have finished it myself. Endrju's solution was incomplete and confusing so i created event and managed textblock in that comboBox1_SelectionChanged event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i have done it using `SelectionChanged` and creating `SelectionChangedEventHandler`. 
The code is as below (may be useful for some future user):

`cb.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChanged);` in `converter()` function and outside converter function :

```
 void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtblk2.Text = cb.SelectedValue.ToString() + " millions";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just when creating the combobox, create also the binding in c#, then it will update the textbox automatically without the need for any events or additional code.

```
  var binding = new Binding("Text");
  binding.Source = cb;
  binding.StringFormat = "{0} millions";
  txtblk2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thanks but shows norhing Inside thet textBox...And please make it textbox, not textblock

Comment: It's not "write the complete code for me" site. The code is an example without even using Visual Studio, just make adjustments, corrections, test it, and I'm sure it will work in 5 minutes.

Comment: also see the GUI snapshot when i selected 10

Comment: @Endruj thanks ofr the idea but it still not working . you xcan see my edited code if you want